# Replace the values in a vector with the keys from a map in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a vector of nondecreasing data. Here is a sample:

```
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 2
 3
 3
 4
 4
 6
```

Clearly there are duplicates *and missing numbers*. I can remove the duplicates using `unique`, so my unique values are:

`uniqueVals = unique(sortedData);`

So far, so good. Now, I want to change the data so that the values in `sortedData` are replaced with their index number in `uniqueVals`. For instance, `uniqueVals` first 5 elements would be `1,2,3,4,6`, with indices `1,2,3,4,5`. I want to change `sortedData` so that 1 maps to 1, 2 maps to 2, 3 to 3, 4 to 4, **6 to 5** and so on.

I know I can create a "map" object, but that seems to just be used to map `uniqueVals` to its index. How do I apply that mapping so that the entries in `sortedData` are changed?

I have no need for this to be a particularly fast operation. `sortedData` contains only a few hundred thousand rows and it only needs to be done once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the third output from [unique](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html)

```
[uniqueVals,~,yourOutput] = unique(sortedData);
```

> yourOutput =
>
> ```
>  1
>  1
>  1
>  2
>  2
>  2
>  2
>  2
>  2
>  2
>  2
>  3
>  3
>  4
>  4
>  5
> ```

Comment: Wow, this is definitely a case of RTFM. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `g = findgroups(sortedData);`, which will give you the group index, where there is one group per unique value. The 2nd output of this tells you the value itself

```
[g, gValue] = findgroups( sortedData );
```